# KineticJS Resize - getting image name

Tags: kineticjs

I am using the demo code which has two images that can be dragged and resized.

I am trying to create an alert that will show the name of the image being resized.

I have successfully added two alerts that show which corner is being resized (eg bottomRight) and the new `x,y` position:

```
anchor.on('dragend', function() {
  group.setDraggable(true);
  layer.draw();
  var pointsa = this.getPosition();
  var nam = this.getName();
  alert(pointsa.x + ',' + pointsa.y);
  alert(nam);
});
```

But I cannot seem to create an alert that tells me which image is being resized?

```
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function update(activeAnchor) {
    var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

    var topLeft = group.find('.topLeft')[0];
    var topRight = group.find('.topRight')[0];
    var bottomRight = group.find('.bottomRight')[0];
    var bottomLeft = group.find('.bottomLeft')[0];
    var image = group.find('.image')[0];

    var anchorX = activeAnchor.x();
    var anchorY = activeAnchor.y();

    // update anchor positions
    switch (activeAnchor.name()) {
      case 'topLeft':
        topRight.y(anchorY);
        bottomLeft.x(anchorX);
        break;
      case 'topRight':
        topLeft.y(anchorY);
        bottomRight.x(anchorX);
        break;
      case 'bottomRight':
        bottomLeft.y(anchorY);
        topRight.x(anchorX); 
        break;
      case 'bottomLeft':
        bottomRight.y(anchorY);
        topLeft.x(anchorX); 
        break;
    }

    image.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition());

    var width = topRight.x() - topLeft.x();
    var height = bottomLeft.y() - topLeft.y();
    if(width && height) {
      image.setSize({width:width, height: height});
    }
  }
  function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
    var stage = group.getStage();
    var layer = group.getLayer();

    var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
      x: x,
      y: y,
      stroke: '#666',
      fill: '#ddd',
      strokeWidth: 2,
      radius: 8,
      name: name,
      draggable: true,
      dragOnTop: false
    });

    anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
      update(this);
      layer.draw();
    });
    anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
      group.setDraggable(false);
      this.moveToTop();
    });
    anchor.on('dragend', function() {
      group.setDraggable(true);
      layer.draw();
      var pointsa = this.getPosition();
      var nam = this.getName();
      alert(pointsa.x + ',' + pointsa.y);
      alert(nam);
    });
    // add hover styling
    anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
      var layer = this.getLayer();
      document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      this.setStrokeWidth(4);
      layer.draw();
    });
    anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
      var layer = this.getLayer();
      document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
      this.strokeWidth(2);
      layer.draw();
    });

    group.add(anchor);
  }
  function loadImages(sources, callback) {
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    for(var src in sources) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
      images[src] = new Image();
      images[src].onload = function() {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
  }
  function initStage(images) {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 578,
      height: 400
    });
    var darthVaderGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
      x: 270,
      y: 100,
      draggable: true
    });
    var yodaGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
      x: 100,
      y: 110,
      draggable: true
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    /*
     * go ahead and add the groups
     * to the layer and the layer to the
     * stage so that the groups have knowledge
     * of its layer and stage
     */
    layer.add(darthVaderGroup);
    layer.add(yodaGroup);
    stage.add(layer);

    // darth vader
    var darthVaderImg = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: images.darthVader,
      width: 200,
      height: 138,
      name: 'image'
    });

    darthVaderGroup.add(darthVaderImg);
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 0, 'topRight');
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 138, 'bottomRight');
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 138, 'bottomLeft');

    darthVaderGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
      this.moveToTop();
    });
    // yoda
    var yodaImg = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: images.yoda,
      width: 93,
      height: 104,
      name: 'image'
    });

    yodaGroup.add(yodaImg);
    addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
    addAnchor(yodaGroup, 93, 0, 'topRight');
    addAnchor(yodaGroup, 93, 104, 'bottomRight');
    addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 104, 'bottomLeft');

    yodaGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
      this.moveToTop();
    });

    stage.draw();
  }

  var sources = {
    darthVader: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
    yoda: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
  };
  loadImages(sources, initStage);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I cannot seem to get this to work. Could you please explain how I can get the group (as an alert) within the anchor.on('dragend', function()

Answer (score 1):

You are naming the anchors identically for your 2 groups (topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft).  Your name does not indicate the group that anchor belongs to.

If you need to know the group you could attach a reference to the anchor:

```
var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
  x: x,
  y: y,
  stroke: '#666',
  fill: '#ddd',
  strokeWidth: 2,
  radius: 8,
  name: name,
  draggable: true,
  dragOnTop: false
});

// attach a `myGroup` property to each anchor so you can later get the group.

anchor.myGroup=group;
```